# How to filter out cycles in CYPHER query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am playing around with an inventory for a network technique.
I got (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dCeL.png):

- Network cards (green
- Switches (blue)
- Ports (red)

ports are PART_OF network cards or switches. Ports are bidirectional connected via 'CON'.

If I now want to get the path from HCA1 to HCA2 I am not only getting the path
`hca1->hca1_port->sw_in_port->sw->sw_out_port->hca2_port->hca2` but also the loops through switch0 and switch1.

My query looks like this:

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(name="Hca1"),  
b=node:node_auto_index(name="Hca2")
MATCH p=a-[r*2..15]-b
return a,b,p`
```

The result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKjLP.png

How do I query for straight pathes without cycles? Anyone?

Cheers
Christian

Comment: Hey, I will not give a full answer because this is repetitive points. So 1. You may want to use new indexes with labels. 2. You can take a look at shortestPath. Both points are in the neo4j documentation.

Comment: OP there's no reason to have bidirectional links here with `CON` I don't think, unless you have different properties on each of those relationships.  You can traverse relationships in either direction, And introduction of those extra relationships is causing some of your loops.  You should probably adjust your model here.

Comment: Hey guys, the network technologie I am modeling uses destination routing and I am planing to add the outgoing routes to the relationship, that's why I got two relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, cool allShortestPaths seems to work for me.

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(name="Hca1"),
      b=node:node_auto_index(name="Hca2")
MATCH p= allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(b))
return a,b,p
```

results in ths graph...

[image]

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Oh and shortest path is also working.

allShortestPaths will be quite big if I push in a bigger topology (CLOS, which has a lot of allShortestPaths

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(name="Hca1"),       
      b=node:node_auto_index(name="Hca6")
MATCH p= allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(b))
RETURN a,b,p
```

returns: [image]

only one of them:

```
MATCH (start:HCA { name:"Hca1" }),(end:HCA { name:"Hca6" }),
p = shortestPath((start)-[*..15]-(end))
RETURN p
```

result: [image]